# jQuery how to declare filter code with .css method

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, css-filters

I was wondering how to solve the next problem:
I have a div that is rotated (315) degrees. Since IE8 does not supports transform property, I can apply the following filter in my stylesheet file:

```
 filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix (M11 = 0.70710678, 0.70710678 = M12,    M21 = -0.70710678, M22 = 0.70710678, sizingMethod = 'auto expand')";
```

But I want to solve this with jQuery with the following piece of code:

```
if (! jQuery.support.leadingWhitespace) {
 // Write your code for IE7 and IE8 browsers
 $ ('div.rotatedspan).css ({
     'filter': 'ProgID: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix (M11 = 0.70710678, 0.70710678 = M12, M21 = -0.70710678, M22 = 0.70710678, sizingMethod ='auto expand')
 });
}
```

But the page stumbles over this section ('auto expand), so the `comma's` around **auto expand**. Does anyone know how to declare **sizingmethod** on a correct way within a CSS method?

Comment: did you mean *declase* or *declare*..?

Comment: @Tilwin Joy I mean declare

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
$('div.rotatedspan').css ({
 'filter': 'ProgID: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix (M11 = 0.70710678, 0.70710678 = M12, M21 = -0.70710678, M22 = 0.70710678, sizingMethod ="auto expand"')
});
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, the syntax is now correct. But my html doesn't seems to effect in IE8